# How to make my top block take up additional empty space using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to use flex-box so the top box (pink box), in my fiddle example, are equal height and the bottom box (orange box) content sits below the top box?

I tried applying `display:flex` to the child elements but that made a new column for the bottom content.

https://jsfiddle.net/b9eyzap3/1/

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  //display: flex;
  width: 33%;
}

.top {
  background-color: pink;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top">
      box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 box 1 
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      second block 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="top">
      box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 box 2 
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      second block 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="top">
      box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 box 3 
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      second block 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which boxes are "top" boxes and which are "bottom"?

Comment: Top box is pink and bottom box is orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To your top class add the following:**

`flex:1;`

**Add following to your box class**

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```